# PhpSpreadsheet insert data in a DB from .xls/.xlsx using the first column value as db column name

Tags: php, mysql, phpspreadsheet

I've created a simple system to upload my .xlsx file into a database. But I have a problem when setting/reading the column as, right now, it works only if I work on a fixed column (sku always in column A for example). But I need to upload the data using the first column value as column name. The first column value of each .xlsx files is the same I used to create my database fields. This is how it works right now:

```
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database_name");

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

if(isset($_POST['import_file_btn'])) 
{
    $allowed_ext = ['xls', 'xlsx'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['import_file']['name'];
    $checking = explode(".", $fileName);
    $file_ext = end($checking);

    if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext))
    {

        $targetPath = $_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name'];
        $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($targetPath);
        $data = $spreadsheet-> getActiveSheet()->toArray();

        foreach ($data as $row)

        
        {
            
            $sku = $row['0'];
            $p_name = $row['1'];
            $id_category = $row['2'];
            $id_brand = $row['3'];
        

            $checkProduct = "SELECT sku FROM ita WHERE sku='$sku'";
            $checkProduct_result = mysqli_query ($con, $checkProduct);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($checkProduct_result) > 0)
            {

                $up_query ="UPDATE ita SET p_name='$p_name', id_category='$id_category', id_brand='$id_brand' WHERE sku='$sku' ";
                $up_result = mysqli_query($con, $up_query);
                $msg = 1;


            }

            else 
            {

                $in_query = "INSERT INTO ita (sku, p_name, id_category, id_brand) VALUES ('$sku','$p_name', '$idcategory', '$id_brand')";
                $in_result = mysqli_query ($con, $in_query);
                $msg = 1;
            }

        }

            if(isset($msg))
            {
                $_SESSION['status'] = "All data where imported right";
                header("Location: index.php");

            }

            else 
            
            {
                $_SESSION['status'] = "Error during file import";
                header("Location: index.php");


            }


            
        }

    }
    else

    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Invalid file format";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit(0);

    }
```

As I said some rows are fixed but others could be not present (for example variable values like color, measures and so on) or could be everywhere (column U or Z).

Any advice on how to change the row system using the first value of each column of my .xlsx file?

Thank you very much!

**- - UPDATE - -**

Following advices I made this changes:

```
$data = $spreadsheet-> getActiveSheet()->toArray();
$firstR = array_values($data[0]);
$flipped = array_flip($firstR);

 foreach ($flipped as $row) {

          $sku = $row[ $flipped['sku'] ];
```

and making a var_dump of $flipped it works correctly but the foreach seems not reading correctly the values as, when I import, I get no error but no data (only 0 on INT db column)

Thanks!

Comment: Just read the column contents from the first line into a numerically indexed array - and then _flip_ that array. Then you can access the column _index_ that belongs to the column _value_ `foo`, via `$flippedArray['foo']`

Comment: Hi @CBroe! First of all, thank you very much for your time. Much appreciated. I ask you a couple of things as I'm still learning. I need to create the array by myself before flipping it? I need to understand well how I can read the values and, then, how to use them as an index. Right? I was looking for some examples to better understand everything and then apply it to my code.

Comment: With `$data = $spreadsheet-> getActiveSheet()->toArray();`, you should probably _have_ that array already, in the first element of $data.

Comment: @CBroe ok perfect, following your advice I got the array converted into a numerical one and flipped and seems to be working well. Now, following your advice, I need to access the column index using foo, right? How can I access the index? Sorry for asking, you'ìll have all my gratitude!

Comment: `foo` was a placeholder for the name of the column you actually want to access. If `sku` was your second column, then your flipped array should contain the value `1` (index of _second_ column) now, under the key `sku`. So when you want to access the value of that column, you now use `$sku = $row[ $flippedArray['sku'] ];`, which would mean the same thing, as if you had accessed `$sku = $row[ 1 ];` to begin with, only _that_ number you didn’t now.

Comment: Ok this is clear! So I have to change it in this way:                                                  
  `$data = $spreadsheet-> getActiveSheet()->toArray();        
   $numerical = array_values ($_POST);
   $flippedArray = array_flip($numerical);
   foreach ($flippedArray as $row) {
   $sku = $row[ $flippedArray['sku'] ]; `